# Chrome 72 now auto closes after script completes

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise Build 1803.

Chrome automatically updated to 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Nothing else has been updated on my computer.

Chrome now automatically terminates at the end of all my Selenium/Python scripts.

I have verified that I am running the latest version of the Chrome Driver.

I know how to update the script to add arguments to not close Chrome, but wondering if anyone else is having this issue.

Below is a sample script for reference:

```
import os
import datetime
import time
import webbrowser
from datetime import timedelta

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import (NoSuchElementException,
                                        StaleElementReferenceException,
                                        TimeoutException,
                                        ElementNotInteractableException,
                                        MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException,
                                        InvalidElementStateException)
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print("Browser: " + driver.name)

if driver.name == "chrome":
    print("Version: " + driver.capabilities['version'])
elif driver.name == 'firefox':
    print("Version: " + driver.capabilities['browserVersion'])
else:
    print("Unable to determine Browser version")
print("--------")

driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)

step = "01"
print("Step " + step + ": Load 21st page and validate")
start = time.time()

driver.get("https://www.21st.com/auto-insurance-quote/?pid=09770999999")

elementName = "//*[@id='id-3aa126ba-0d02-4e95-88c2-b89d342accc5']"
try:
    start2 = time.time()
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "" + elementName + "")))
    stop2 = time.time()
    print("Step " + step + ": WebDriverWait Response Time (sec) to see " + elementName + " id is " + str(stop2 - start2))
except:
    stop = time.time()
    print("Step " + step + ": Response Time (sec) is " + str(stop - start))
    raise Exception ("WARNING: Could not find " + elementName + "")
    print("--------")

stop = time.time()
print("Step " + step + ": Response Time (sec) is " + str(stop - start))
print("--------")
```

**Update**
My IDE is Visual Studio Code. I just found out that the Python extension was automatically updated on 1/29. I wonder if this is the reason Chrome is closing at the end of the script.

Comment: _Chrome now automatically terminates at the end of all my Selenium/Python scripts_ ... which script? Why do you want to keep em open? What is your usecase?

Comment: I've only been scripting for 4 months. I don't know any different. From the beginning, none of the browsers closed after completion. Today was the first day I saw it. I'll edit the post with a sample script.

Answer (score 0):

It was the new version (2019.1.0) of the extension that cause it. I reverted to the previous version (2018.12.1) and Chrome did not close.